# Index of intersections of subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've been having some problems with three related problems on a review sheet for finals. Is it possible to get some information on how I should approach these problems?

1. Suppose that N is a normal subgroup of G of index 2 and let K $\le$ G. Prove that (K : K $\cap$ N) = 1 or 2.
2. Suppose that N is a normal subgroup of G of index 3 and let K $\le$ G. Prove that (K : K $\cap$ N) = 1 or 3.
3. Suppose that N is a subgroup of index 3 and let K $\le$ G. Prove that (K : K $\cap$ N) $\le$ 3.

What I've tried so far:

I've attempted to use the fact that (G : K $\cap$ N) = (G : N)(N : N $\cap$ K) = (G : K)(K : N $\cap$ K) in each problem to little success.

I've tried considering the homomorphism:
$$\phi: G  \to G/N$$
$$g \mapsto gN$$

restricted to K,
$$\phi|_K: K \to G/N$$
$$g \mapsto gN$$

Looking at ker($\phi$) = N, and for the restricted map ker($\phi|_K$) = K $\cap$ N.

From here I'm not sure where to go. Neither attempt seems to have gotten me anywhere. What am I missing?

Comment: Hint: There is a theorem that $K/(N\cap K)$ is isomorphic to $NK/N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

$$\,N\lhd G\implies H\cap N\lhd H\stackrel{3rd\;\text{isom. theorem}}\implies H/(H\cap N)\cong HN/N\implies$$

$$[H:H\cap N]=[HN: N]\le [G:N]\;\ldots$$

Further hint: always, $\,[HN:N]\;\mid\; [G:N]\,$

Comment: Wow! Thanks for mentioning by name the 3rd isomorphism theorem. The book we're using (Fraleigh) doesn't really go in depth on all of these and I had forgotten about them. This is very helpful.

Comment: Any time, @DylanFoster . In fact, mentioning "third", "second" or "first" isomorphism theorem can be risky, since different authors number them differently. I've seen even the Correspondence theorem called the fourth isomorphism theorem...

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this property that if $K$ and $N$ are subgroups of a group $G$, then $$[K:K\cap N]\leq [G:N]$$ Here you have $[G:N]\leq2$ so...

Comment: $\Large + 1 \quad \ddot\smile\quad$